# Veeam Backup job in two NAS at once

Tags: backup, veeam

can someone assist - we were looking to backup to a local NAS but also to a external NAS ? (the two nas can ping )

I cant see a way to have two backups run one after the other in the same job.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The is the function of a Veeam Backup Copy Job. It will use the first backup as the source for the second backup. See documentation [here](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/backup_copy.html?ver=95u4)

Alternatively, you could use native NAS replication to move the target files to the second NAS.